# Cannot connect Smart Glass to Xbox

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-smartglass

I can't get my Smart Glass app to connect with my Xbox 360. I have tried the app on 3 different phones running 3 different versions of android (ver4.4, 5.0 and 6.0). I have turned on the Smart Glass settings on the console, the console is connected to the internet, and I am signed in to the same profile on both the app and the console. The phone and console are on the same network, although the Xbox is plugged into a LAN port and the phone obviously connects via Wifi.

When using another casting app, I can successfully cast images and audio to the Xbox, so the phone and console CAN exchange data. But Smart Glass just refuses to work. I have the latest version of the app and the latest updates from Xbox Live.

So if anyone has any ideas over and above the stuff over at support.xboxlive.com, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your router support network isolation? Since the LAN + WiFi are different networks, some routers make it so devices on one can't see devices on the other. Maybe look into your router settings, and turn this off if it is on?

Comment: I had a look and could not find such a setting. I also couldn't view or modify subnet properties of the Wifi. I'll consult the manual and see if I can learn anything.

I could however cast from my phone to the console using another image/audio casting app.

Comment: UPDATE: Wifi isolation is turned off. Still no luck.

Comment: You are trying to use the Xbox 360 smartglass app and not the Xbox app(Xbox One only)

Comment: Yes. Because I have an Xbox 360